# How to store image questions in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I am making a quiz web app which randomly generates questions. My certain questions have images in them. I want to know how should I go about storing my questions. Some questions are only text whereas some questions are text plus image

Comment: My understanding is u r trying to store image in DB.For this u have to use `BLOB` datatype in dB...But this is not a recommended way.. u better store image location.

Comment: As Suganthan has said, BLOB datatype can be used to store any kind of data in the database (images, Word documents, other database files) but the catch is that your database doesn't understand the contents. It is just an object which the database doesn't manipulate, but just stores and retrieves. This means that for an image, a database query can't display it. You need some other program to read it from the database and do something with it (write it to a file, display it etc).